# Heltec ESP32 WIFI LORA V2 serial output on GPIO is incorrect

Tags: arduino, serial-port, uart

I am trying to implement a simple program on my ESP32 and am having an issue with the output.  I am simply sending "1000" to both serial ports setup.  The Arduino IDE Serial Monitor displays the correct output, however, the serial2 output displays HEX.

Here is the test code I am attempting to get the serial output from:

```
#define TXD1 13  // GPIO pin for transmit


void setup() {
  // Start communication on UART0 (USB)
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Start communication on UART1
  Serial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, -1, TXD1);
}

void loop() {
  // Write data to UART0 (USB)
  Serial.println("1000");
  // Write the same data to UART1
  Serial1.println("1000");
  delay(1000);  // Wait for a second
}
```

I have verified all my connections, even purchasing logic level shifters and installing one. I get the exact same output, I have verified the baud rate, flow control and stop bits:

g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}  (repeats)

This is the output from the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE:

```
12:29:29.781 -> [0;32mI (1355314) main: 1000
12:29:29.781 -> [0m
12:29:30.801 -> [0;32mI (1356314) main: 1000
12:29:30.801 -> [0m
12:29:31.809 -> [0;32mI (1357314) main: 1000
12:29:31.809 -> [0m
```

Any output on the GPIO (doesnt matter which pin) I get the above hex (g{\xf6}{\xf6}{\xb6}{SI}{NUL}).

I have used an Arduino UNO and got the same result.

I have also tried loading a different serial library (#include <HardwareSerial.h>), however, this also displayed the same result.

I have also installed PlatformIO on Visual Studio Code and implemented the ESP-IDF framework:

```
#include "driver/uart.h"
#include "esp_vfs_dev.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

#define ECHO_TEST_TXD  (4)    // Change to GPIO4 for TX
#define ECHO_TEST_RXD  (5)   // Change to GPIO5 for RX
#define ECHO_TEST_RTS  (UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE)
#define ECHO_TEST_CTS  (UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE)

#define BUF_SIZE (1024)

void app_main(void)
{
    /* Configure parameters of an UART driver, 
    * communication pins and install the driver */
    uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 9600,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
        .source_clk = UART_SCLK_APB,
    };
    
    // Install UART driver, and get the queue.
    uart_driver_install(UART_NUM_1, BUF_SIZE * 2, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
    uart_param_config(UART_NUM_1, &uart_config);
    uart_set_pin(UART_NUM_1, ECHO_TEST_TXD, ECHO_TEST_RXD, ECHO_TEST_RTS, ECHO_TEST_CTS);

    while(1) {
        // Write data to UART.
        const char* test_str = "1000\n";
        uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM_1, test_str, strlen(test_str));

        // Write the same data to the USB serial port
        ESP_LOGI("main", "1000\n");

        // Delay for 1 second
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

This also presented the same output on the serial GPIO.

Any indication on where to look next is appreciated!